# Java Constructor with ImageIcon

Tags: java, user-interface

I created a small program that inserts an ImageIcon (resized in another class) into a JLabel through a constructor
I am struggling to return the icon in the JLabel

Here's my code:

**Main Class**:

```
        traforma imageObj = new traforma("image1.png"); //traforma is another class

        ImageIcon Icon11 = new ImageIcon(imageObj.Icon11);

         imageLabel.setIcon(Icon11);  //Here he gives me error, he can't find my ' Icon11 '
```

**traforma Class**:

```
public class traforma {


    public  traforma(String image) {
        ImageIcon Icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(image));
        Image image = Icon1.getImage(); 
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(470, 360,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon Icon11 = new ImageIcon(newimg);

    }
    Object Icon11 = this.Icon11; // i guess the problem is here


}
```

I am new to Java,
Hope I have been clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes no sense:

```
Object Icon11 = this.Icon11;
```

The problem is, that the variable "Icon11" that you initialized within the method is not used anywhere. After method completed, it will be thrown away. What you can do, is to assign the created icon object to the *member* variable, not to the *local* variable.

Thy style of your code is not perfect: the usage of lower and upper case, the usage of ImageIcon instead of directly loading image, etc. But if we keep it as close to your code as possible and try to do minimal changes, the working code may look as follows:

```
public class traforma {

    public  traforma(String image) {
        ImageIcon Icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(image));
        Image image = Icon1.getImage(); 
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(470, 360,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        this.Icon11 = new ImageIcon(newimg);
    }

    public ImageIcon Icon11;

}
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to Java (or coding in General)

Comment: Everyone was once new to Java and to programming in general :) Try to understand what you read. Try to create examples to what you read to check if you understood that correctly.

Comment: If I Can ask, What Should I do to adjust my code? I want to improve

Comment: Thanks, I'll do what you suggested!

Comment: I have given an example how could you change your code to make it work. But if you mean "in general": There is an idea of "coding style". If you follow some style, your code can be easier to read, also some errors can be found easier. In particular, in Java it is a good style if class names start with an upper case letter, variable names start with a lower case - then you can easier distinguish what is what. Variable names should reflect their purpose, not just "icon1", "icon11" - in 3 months you will be not able to understand your own code. It's impossible to put everything into a comment :)

Comment: You are right.
This program is just one example ( like you said before ).
 I want to create more and more of these examples ( like using Layout Mangers, use more complex constructors etc...), and from now I'll be careful with my next programs.

Classes names should be with upper case letter and variable names start with lower, 
and I should name the variables with names that reflect their use, 
this only serves to make the program more readable, right?
Last question then you are free xD :
What "this " means.. like " this.Icon11"


Thank you and good day! ^^

Comment: In your example, class "traforma" is kind of template for objects that your will create. Each object will have field (in other words "member variable") "Icon11". Any variables defined within a method will be thrown away after method completed. But all fields (member variables) like "Icon11" will remain the whole time the object exists. The word "this" shows that you refer not a variable defined within the method, but a variable *outside* of the method, the object field.